# Can't install packages for Hardhat project

Tags: npm, ethereum, hardhat

I wanted to create a project using Hardhat environment. I've tried following https://hardhat.org/getting-started/ tutorial from their side. In there, we have a TIP to install all required packages. Unfortunately when I run `npm install --save-dev @nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle ethereum-waffle chai @nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers ethers` first I can see a lot of warnings about deprecated packages and then

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-abi.git
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\(path)
```

I've tried installing `ethereum-waffle` with specific version selected etc. it always ends with the same error.

Do you know how to overcome it? Why so many packages are deprecated during install? Is this `getting-started` outdated and I should start hardhat project in some other way?

Comment: Likely you do not have git installed

Comment: Thanks, that solved the same issue for me!

Answer (score 0):

When you run *npm install --save-dev @nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle ethereum-waffle chai @nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers ethers* , you are installing both. The @nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers plugin is meant to be a drop-in replacement for the @nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle plugin. So having just one is okay. I recommend you to migrate and use the Hardhat Chai Matchers plugin.
Use this link for more information. => "https://hardhat.org/hardhat-chai-matchers/docs/migrate-from-waffle". I hope this helps out a little bit.